# android make view to wrap content but not larger than a specific size

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a Relative View which has two children an scroll view and a button below it now i want to do this: i want this view to wrap it's content and does not make empty space and also not to exceed screen size.
how can i do that? can any one help?

here is my current layout file which is not working.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
              ....
     </ScrollView>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/content" 
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set android:maxHeight="your height in dp" on that view

Comment: now how it is looking ? can you attach screenshoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` does not have such possibility. However `LinearLayout` does. Just set `LinearLayout`'s `android:orientation` to `vertical`, set `ScrollView`'s `android:layout_weight` to `1`, and it should be working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearLayout and adjust both the views according to a weight.In that way it will not exceed in any resolution and will adjust acording to the size of screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewPort="true"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
     </ScrollView>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/content" 
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make action button align at the bottom  and that scroll view should be above that button. In this way scroll view will always be in screen and also button will be visible.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            ... />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/action"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                  ....
         </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```